# how to store users activity and operations in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, logging

In my laravel 5 project i need to store all user actions, 
if user has login and logout and doing some actions in laravel db it must be stored into an file or something for feature use.
i have a tip to doing  these things ,i need some guidelines, how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

hi try this laravel package can help you to solve your problem its good user activity package

https://github.com/spatie/activitylog